# Why can't an interface extends Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I'm trying to implement the Iterator for an ArrayList. I have an interface for ArrayList, and I also want it to implements the Iterator, so I can provide the implementations in the actual ArrayList class. The interface is like:

```
public interface AListInterface<T> extends Iterator<T> {

       add();
       remove();
       ......

}
```

But I'm getting the error says I'll have to import the java.util.Iterator. So I'm confused, I thought once imported a class, then I can just use all the methods that already been implemented like a Scanner. Then what is the point of import the Iterator interface and at the meantime also needs to provide the implementations?

And also, if i change the heading of my AListInterface to:

```
public interface AListInterface<T> extends Iterable<T> { }
```

It compiles fine, so why is it okay to extends Iterable instead of Iterator?

Comment: To let Java compiler know which Iterable you are referring in code you need to import in Java source. Compiler will refer to it . Say `import java.util.Iterator;` after package declaration on the top of Java source file

Comment: Java will only import `java.lang.*` by default. If you want to use something in `java.util` or `java.lang.reflect`, you have to import it explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

> Why can't an interface `extends Iterator`?

It can. See for example [`java.util.ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

> But I'm getting the error says I'll have to import the `java.util.Iterator`.

So import it.

> So I'm confused

I agree.

> I thought once imported a class, then I can just use all the methods that already been implemented like a Scanner.

No, it primarily means you can use the *name* of the class without qualification.

> Then what is the point of import the Iterator interface

So you can use the name `Iterator` without qualification.

> and at the meantime also needs to provide the implementations?

You don't. You're defining an interface. No method implementations required. And providing method implementations has nothing to do with importing.

> why is it okay to extends `Iterable` instead of `Iterator`?

Because you must have imported it.